Where do I find the "jobid" parameter when using the Get Job Status API for the Azure AI Video Indexer?
The documentation for the AVI is poor and it does not reference where to get this parameter.
It is not mentioned in any of the other APIs that I can see, and it is not an optional parameter.
Where do I find this parameter from my uploads and what format to use?

Provide the documentation you are referring.

After calling Upload Video API you will find the id parameter in the response body.
you can query the video object and check the state of the indexing process:
Uploaded , Processing , Processed , Failed.
The state is available in Get Video Index for a specific video and in List Videos you can check the state for all videos.
We will update our documentation to reflect this better.

Thanks for this. There needs to be a similar API to check progress for creating prompt content. As it is not an instant process, I am having to do an inelegant solution whereby the call to Get Prompt Content is looped with a 1 second delay until a successful response is received back. I think this could be prone to errors.

For Prompt Content:
Call Post request and get Accepted (202)
The response will contain a header named 'location' which is used for the polling, it's built in a way you can call Get directly from this header in order to get the status (which will return 200)
Once completed, you will receive 303 (redirect) and the location-header will point to the created resource.
